# Calculate DateTime from NTP timestamp on embedded device

Tags: embedded, device, ntp

I have a very limited environment which have no standard linux/unix date/time API and have to synchronize clock against `NTP` server. I can communicate via `UDP` and get `NTP` reply. Now i need to convert `NTP timestamp` to the device date/time completly by myself.

I've found several ntp implementations (`qntp`, `c#`, `java`) but they all using system wide functions to convert `NTP` timestamp to the corresponding DateTime implementation.

Any avdice to how to convert or any links where i can read about such a conversion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Resolved. In case if someone interresting in it - Qt sources contains excelent implementation of exactly what i'm looking for. qdatetime.cpp getDateFromJulianDay is the way how to convert julian date to d/m/y. and julianDayFromDate gives the offset for ntp 1900-01-01. The rest become trivial.

Comment: submit your answer and mark this as answered

Comment: @user1171379 please provide a solution in the answer

Comment: It won't work for all dates.  NTP uses eras and leap seconds.  NOT simple, in it's purest form.